# Copy ranges to master table and remove ranges from master table if cell = 0

Tags: vba, excel

There are 10 Sheets (Sheet1...Sheet10) with tables in the same range (C25:G34 & C42:N51).

[image: Worksheets Source Tables]

The rows have to be copied if the 'Total Weight' column has value > 0. The copied rows go to two summary tables:

To Westrock Table -> Westrock Summary Table

To DNP Table -> DNP Summary Table

Summary Table:
Westrock
[image: Westrock Summary]

Summary Table:
DNP
[image]

I'm on Mac, so PowerQuery is not an option. I'm new to VBA; this is what I have so far:

```
Sub ToDNP()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Worksheets("Jupiter").Activate
Range("C42:N51").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("To DNP").Activate
Range("C11").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
'Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("Windsor").Activate
Range("C42:N51").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("To DNP").Activate
Range("C21").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Worksheets("Orlando").Activate
Range("C42:N51").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("To DNP").Activate
Range("C31").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Worksheets("Woodland").Activate
Range("C42:N51").Select
Selection.Copy
Worksheets("To DNP").Activate
Range("C41").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False


Dim rRow As Integer, rCol As Integer
Dim cRow As Integer, cCol As Integer

rCol = 3
rRow = 11
cCol = 14
cRow = 11

For cRow = 11 To 50

    If Cells(cCol, cRow).Value = "0" Then
        Range(Cells(rCol, rRow), Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents
    End If
    rRow = rRow + 1

Next cRow

End Sub
```

This is giving me an error:

> Error: Cannot change part of a merged Cell

Comment: What line is giving you that error?

Comment: Range(Cells(rCol, rRow), Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents There are no merged cells anywhere

Comment: How can you be so sure that `Range(Cells(rCol, rRow), Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents` does not contain any merged cells? Did you check on **all** sheets? Because this line of code does not refer to any particular sheet. So, it could be `Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(rCol, rRow), Sheet1.Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents` or `Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(rCol, rRow), Sheet2.Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents` or `Sheet3.Range(Sheet3.Cells(rCol, rRow), Sheet3.Cells(cCol, cRow)).ClearContents` .... and so on for all 10 sheets.

Comment: @Ralph Actually, that line of code ***does*** refer to a particular worksheet - the active sheet. Which, if you look at the preceding code, is the `To DNP` worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the error because you have the row and column values swapped around. The row parameter comes first and *then* comes the column parameter.

Your code should read as follows:

```
If Cells(cRow, cCol).Value = "0" Then
    Range(Cells(rRow, rCol), Cells(cRow, cCol)).ClearContents
End If
```

You are trying to clear column 11 from rows 3 to 14 of the "To DNP" worksheet, which obviously contains merged cells.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that stops by; here is simple code to clear a specific range in a row if one cell contains a specific value.

```
For Each cell In Range("C11:N50")
   If cell.Value2 = "0" Then
        Set cRng = Range("C" & cell.Row & ":" & "O" & cell.Row)
        ' Or Set clearRng = Range("C" & cell.Row & ":O" & cell.Row)
        cRng.Clear
   End If
Next
```